# Distiller Settings in XeLaTeX PDF

Tags: xetex

Since the PDF is getting generated from XeLaTeX, i want to add the distiller option (some of the mention below in the form of bullet list) into the generated PDF. Most of the PDF requirements are based on the PS to PDF with provided distiller settings. How to achieve this. Because of this i couldn't migrate from LaTeX to XeLaTeX.

**Eg (Distiller Options)**:

1. Image resolution
2. PDF Version 1.3
3. Resolution 2400
4. Color images=Zip, Grayscale images= Zip, 1Bit image or Monochrome=CCITT4 group4
5. Embedded subset
6. Color = leave color unchanged
7. Preserve Overprint settings

Comment: Most of those don't make sense for a program which is simply going to be passing things in to the .pdf un-changed --- if you want specifications like that you'll need to apply them to the graphics before placing them w/ xelatex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about setting the particular options, but I can help to get you started. By default `xelatex` appears to produce PDF directly, hiding the fact that is uses `xdvipdfmx` behind the scenes to do the "distilling".

To pass various options to `xdvipdfmx`, you can run instead

```
xelatex -no-pdf <name>.tex
xdvipdfmx <name>.xdv
```

You can then run `texdoc xdvipdfmx` to assess whether it has the options you need. E.g.,

```
xdvipdfmx -V 3 <name>.xdv
```

will give you PDF version 1.3 output.

Comment: Or `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V 3" <name>`, without two commands.

Comment: Thanks, its helps me partially, suppose if i want to change the encoding from Identity-H to Ansi in PDF to avoid compiste fonts, i couldnt do that is there any solution for this.